# Couldn't cast SwiftUI.ExtensionDelegate to ExtensionDelegate

Tags: swiftui, watchos

Working working with a SwiftUI Architecture WatchOS app, if you want to use ExtensionDelegate you need to create your own.  I have done this, but when I try to actually access the delegate in the code, I am getting the following error message Could not cast value of type `SwiftUI.ExtensionDelegate' (0x7fff8441b480) to 'TestMe_WatchKit_Extension.ExtensionDelegate' (0x10c3b36d0).`
I have defined the ExtensionDelegate as -

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    var meetingStatistics:  MeetingStatistics = MeetingStatistics()
    override init(){
        super.init()
    }
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.
        print("applicationDidFinishLaunching for watchOS")
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
    }
}
```

in my @main - I have the following:

```
@main
struct WatchApp: App {
@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate
// code

}
```

When I try to access the delegate as -
`let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate` I get the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, - in the meantime I collected more experience. For my application delegate it is important that it is a singleton (only one instance exists). I realised that I have two.

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var applicationDelegate
```

in the SwiftUI App struct initialises the first. To this App struct I added a init() method.

```
 init() {
  
  AppDelegate.shared = self.applicationDelegate
}
```

That initialises my AppDelegate static variable "shared" very early in the programme.

I removed all @Environment based access to the delegate, the key, the default value etc.. Global access is insured by

```
AppDelegate.shared
```

The issue with the self-defined @Environment variables is, that they can only be set with an .environment(_ keyPath:, _ value:) modifier on a view. However, my delegate is accessed before the first view sets the environment variable. Hence, my AppDelegate shared variable is now an ordinary static variable which I set myself as early as possible: in the init() method of the App struct.

Answer (score 10):

The `WKExtension.shared().delegate` is not your ExtensionDelegate but **internal** `SwiftUI.ExtensionDelegate` (as stated), which provides your adapter **delegate**. You must use (pass everywhere) *only* instance of adapter delegate provided for your via

```
@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate
```

**Update:**

To use your `delegate` you have to pass it as argument next to view, eg as environment (so you can use it in any subview as `@Environment(\.appDelegate) var appDelegate`

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
       ContentView()
          .environment(\.appDelegate, delegate)
    }
}
```

and

```
struct DelegateKey: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = ExtensionDelegate?
    static let defaultValue: ExtensionDelegate? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var appDelegate: DelegateKey.Value {
        get {
            return self[DelegateKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DelegateKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I am not getting the error when trying to access it in as an @environmentObject  - but when trying to access it in another class - that is where I have the ` let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate` - given this.

Comment: I am using this code between iOS, macOS, tvOs, and watchOS, only watchOS broke the delegate. ```    #if os(macOS)
    let delegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    #elseif os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    #elseif os(watchOS)
    let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate
    #endif```

Comment: I am still getting <uninitialized> in the debugger when I go to access `let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate`

Comment: How would I access the delegate from a place that's not a view, eg `IntentHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in macOS. After declaring a class as the application delegate using in the @main App struct:

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var applicationDelegate
```

The AppDelegate is correctly initialised when the Application launches.
I declare the environment key:

```
struct DelegateKey: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = AppDelegate
    static let defaultValue: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var appDelegate: DelegateKey.Value {
        get {
            return self[DelegateKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DelegateKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

to access the variable via
`@Environment(\.appDelegate) var appDelegate`

That is fine for all SwiftUI environments.
The problem is that the general access to the application delegate via
`NSApp.delegate`
does not work any longer.

The solution is to declare a static variable in the AppDelegate class itself:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
   
   @Environment(\.appDelegate) static var shared
}
```

This makes the instantiated AppDelegate object accessible from everywhere via:
`AppDelegate.shared`
.

Comment: Thanks this helped clarify, but when I try to access the AppDelegate its value is nil

Comment: I am still getting a nil value when I try to access this value in my related class, which is created in the app Launch. It appears to be that AppDelegate is not created before the init of the ExtensionDelegate

Comment: I checked the initialisation of my AppDelegate via a comment line in the init() method. It is initialised very early when my application starts. This is probably due to the definition of the default value in the ````struct DelegateKey ````which instantiate it. Here, I deviate from the common use pattern by not declaring it nil and not declaring it an optional value.

Comment: M Wilm, I tried initalizing with a the same `struct DelegateKey: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = ExtensionDelegate?
    static let defaultValue: ExtensionDelegate? = ExtensionDelegate()
}` but that still ends up with the original error.